# Iterating on nested arrays in objects to collate informaton

Tags: javascript

I have the following array of objects:

```
let array = [
{key: 'Newcastle', values[
  {key: 'ID1000', values[
    {name: 'Jeff', cust_id: "ID1000", status: 'sold'},
    {name: 'Jeff', cust_id: "ID1000", status: 'pending'},
  ]}
  {key: 'ID2000', values [
    {name: 'Bob', cust_id: "ID2000", status: 'sold'}
  ]}
]}
{key: 'London', values [
 {key: 'ID3000', values[
  {name: 'Gary', cust_id: "ID3000", status: 'sold'},
 ]}
 {key: 'ID4000', values[
  {name: 'Mary', cust_id: "ID4000", status: 'interest'},
  {name: 'Mary', cust_id: "ID4000", status: 'interest'},
  {name: 'Mary', cust_id: "ID4000", status: 'pending'},
 ]}
]}
]
```

I have been trying to refactor it into something like:

```
[
 {Location: 'Newcastle, customers: 2, sold: 2, pending: 1, interest: 0},
 {Location: 'London', customers: 2, sold: 1, pending: 1, interest: 2}
]
```

So I am attempting to count the number of status events and collate them accordingly.

I get lost when I try to iterate on the nested arrays and then when trying to bubble up the results of the iteration to a final object. The closest I have got is:

```
function transform(array) {
      let arr = []
      array.forEach(function(x) {
        function soldCount() {
          x.values.forEach(function(x) {

            let sold = x.values.forEach(function(x) {
              let soldTrue = 0
              if (x.status === "sold") {
                soldTrue++
              }
              console.log(soldTrue)
              if (soldTrue > 0) {
                return soldTrue
              }
            })

          })
        }
        let obj = {
          location: x.key,
          customers: x.values.length,
          sold: soldCount()
        }

        arr.push(obj)
      })
      return arr
    }
```

This tries to iterate on each array in the objects and attempts to return a number for how many of the 'sold' status it finds. The console statement does return a number but it returns multiple entries for each item in the array due to 'forEach'.

I am swamped in a number of forEach loops iterating on nested arrays. I suspect that this might not be the correct methodology for what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take an object counting `status` and build a new objects.

```js
var array = [{ key: 'Newcastle', values: [{ key: 'ID1000', values: [{ name: 'Jeff', cust_id: "ID1000", status: 'sold' }, { name: 'Jeff', cust_id: "ID1000", status: 'pending' },] }, { key: 'ID2000', values: [{ name: 'Bob', cust_id: "ID2000", status: 'sold' }] }] }, { key: 'London', values: [{ key: 'ID3000', values: [{ name: 'Gary', cust_id: "ID3000", status: 'sold' },] }, { key: 'ID4000', values: [{ name: 'Mary', cust_id: "ID4000", status: 'interest' }, { name: 'Mary', cust_id: "ID4000", status: 'interest' }, { name: 'Mary', cust_id: "ID4000", status: 'pending' }] }] }],
    result = array.map(({ key: Location, values }) => {
        var data = { Location, customers: 0, sold: 0, pending: 0, interest: 0 };
        values.forEach(({ values }) => {
            data.customers++;
            values.forEach(({ status }) => data[status]++);
        });
        return data;
    });

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I've marked this one as accepted because I like how contained and concise it is. It should have occured to me that if I wanted to create a new array I should be looking at .map instead of drowning in .forEach loops

Answer (score 2):

Look at this:

```
let array = [
{
  key: 'Newcastle', 
  values: [
  {key: 'ID1000', 
   values:[
    {name: 'Jeff', cust_id: "ID1000", status: 'sold'},
    {name: 'Jeff', cust_id: "ID1000", status: 'pending'},
  ]},
  {
    key: 'ID2000', 
    values :[
    {name: 'Bob', cust_id: "ID2000", status: 'sold'}
  ]
  }
]},
{key: 'London', values :[
 {key: 'ID3000', values:[
  {name: 'Gary', cust_id: "ID3000", status: 'sold'},
 ]},
 {key: 'ID4000', values:[
  {name: 'Mary', cust_id: "ID4000", status: 'interest'},
  {name: 'Mary', cust_id: "ID4000", status: 'interest'},
  {name: 'Mary', cust_id: "ID4000", status: 'pending'},
 ]}
]}
]

function countProp(arr, prop) {
    let n = 0;
    arr.forEach((items) => {
      items.values.forEach(item => {
            if (item.status === prop) {
                n += 1;
            }
        })
    });
    return n;
}

const n = array.map(item => {
  const a = {};
  a.customers = item.values.length;
  a.location = item.key;
  a.sold = countProp(item.values, "sold");
  a.pending = countProp(item.values, "pending");
  a.interest = countProp(item.values, "interest");
  return a;
});
```

This gives

```
[
 {Location: 'Newcastle, customers: 2, sold: 2, pending: 1, interest: 0},
 {Location: 'London', customers: 2, sold: 1, pending: 1, interest: 2}
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Assumingly you are using `let`.
I have written my solution in ES6, getting Location, customer count is easy.

The challenging part would be the accumulating the status count per type of status, you can use reduce with object as initial value and using  the status types as keys with 0 initial value, which shown in my solution

```js
let array = [
{key: 'Newcastle', values: [
  {key: 'ID1000', values: [
    {name: 'Jeff', cust_id: "ID1000", status: 'sold'},
    {name: 'Jeff', cust_id: "ID1000", status: 'pending'}
  ]},
  {key: 'ID2000', values: [
    {name: 'Bob', cust_id: "ID2000", status: 'sold'}
  ]}
]},
{key: 'London', values: [
 {key: 'ID3000', values: [
  {name: 'Gary', cust_id: "ID3000", status: 'sold'}
 ]},
 {key: 'ID4000', values:[
  {name: 'Mary', cust_id: "ID4000", status: 'interest'},
  {name: 'Mary', cust_id: "ID4000", status: 'interest'},
  {name: 'Mary', cust_id: "ID4000", status: 'pending'}
 ]}
]}
];

const newArray = array.map((a) => {
   const Location = a.key;
   const customer = a.values.length;
   const status = a.values.reduce((acc, value) => {
      value.values.forEach((v1) => {
        acc[v1.status] = acc[v1.status] + 1;
      });
      return acc;
   }, {sold: 0, pending: 0, interest: 0});
   return {Location, customer, ...status};
});

console.log(newArray);
```